# How to make my app with transparrent theme?

Tags: android, themes, transparency

I am making my Music player now. I want it to be lightly transparent(Android background barely visable). Structure: One activity with 4 fragments (viewPager with tabs). Any ideas?

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this theme in your Activity's theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

This will make the background of your ACtivity completely transparent. You can also extend that theme and set a custom windowBackground

In your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyTransparentTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="windowBackground">@color/my_transparent_color</item>
</style>
```

In case you are using `AppCompat` you should change the parent theme to

```
<style name="MyTransparentTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="windowBackground">@color/my_transparent_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: You are using AppCompat. In this case parent should use AppCompat alternative. Updating the answer now.

Comment: posted edit of my styles.xml. What do i have to change. This part of my app is quite new to me.